# Error: Container localhost does not exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to deploy a CNN model through the Google Cloud API. The model has already been uploaded to Google Cloud. I specified, while creating my Cloud Bucket, a Python version of 3.7, and Tensorflow 2.1.0. I'm trying to deploy by running the following code in my Anaconda terminal:

```
gcloud ai-platform predict --region europe-west1 --model <model name> --version <version name> --json-instances check_deployed_model/test.json
```

However, the following error keeps popping up, even after double checking my model was indeed trained in Tensorflow 2.1.0:

*ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.predict) HTTP request failed. Response: {
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "{ "error": "Error while reading resource variable conv2d/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv2d/bias)\n\t [[{{node model/sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp}}]]" }",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}*

I have already tried [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28287#issuecomment-495005162) advice, but I couldn't seem to make it work.

Any advice on how I could proceed?